# Reasons when a java program throws ServiceException (javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException)?

Tags: java, rpc

Could someone let me know in what are the use cases the javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException will be thrown?

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the methods in **Service**(javax.xml.rpc.Service) Interface or the **ServiceFactory**(javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory) class will throw ServiceException.

some of the example condtions are,

1. exception in creating a Service
2. when specifing a illegal endpoint while creating a Service
3. any error in creating a Call(javax.xml.rpc.Call) object
4. error when loading a service or creating a ServiceFactory instance.

Answer (score 1):

Service exceptions are thrown usually when the service is not accessible or if the service is not defined properly and has some errors. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

We use Service Exceptions for throwing environment & data & business exceptions. Here are some examples:

- Environment setting/property does not exist or is blank, that drives logic such as file names to send to another application. So likely what happened is we configured UAT for this environment property but forgot to promote that property to Prod, or someone removed it not realize it would create a defect;
- Upstream system that called our service did not follow the business rules and we cannot process this transaction

In both examples, we:

1. Throw a new ServiceException with a specific message;
2. In the calling logic we Catch that ServiceException;
3. Then throw a new ServiceException with a message: current context string + GetMessage of the caught exception.